# Querying 2 tables using dataset in Visual basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset

I need help with my visual basic project. I have a Store.accdb database
which has 2 tables, customers and orders. I would like to be able to enter a customer's name (or part of a name) in a textbox and then display the name/s in a DataGridView when the search button is clicked. And then On a separate DataGridView I'd like to display the orders of the selected customer from my first DataGridView when the user clicks the Display button.

Edit: This is what the 2 tables look like

Customers table = custNum, custName, custAddress, custPhone

Orders table = orderNum, orderItem, custNum, price, qty

```
con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    Try
        con.Open()
        sql = "SELECT custName FROM tblCustomers WHERE custName LIKE '%" & tbSearch.Text.ToUpper & "%'"
        ds = New DataSet
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "CustomerDataset")
        gridCustomers.DataSource = ds
        gridCustomers.DataMember = "CustomerDataSet"

        con.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could not establish a connection", "Database Error")
    End Try
```

This code works fine, it populates my customers datagridview. I get multiple rows whenever I only enter part of a customer's name. If I enter 'sm' in the textbox, it would display all customers with 'sm' in their name. How can I display the selected customer's (from 1st datagridview) orders in my 2nd datagridview when i click the display button? I hope I am making sense, english is not my first language so please bear with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with many events.
when selecting a customer from `datagridview` you have to use `datagridview's selectedIndexChange` event(assuming you have button to select in `datagridview`)

You have to use the same procedure in `datagridview's selectedIndexChange` event

```
con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

Try
    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblorders WHERE custName ='" & gridSelectedValue & "'"
    //Assuming you have custName column in order table
    ds = New DataSet
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "OrderDataset")
    gridCustomers.DataSource = ds
    gridCustomers.DataMember = "OrderDataset"

    con.Close()


Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.message)
End Try
```

**Edit** 
If you dont have custName in order **Then** you should have CustNum in your query of DataGridView.

Comment: I don't have custName in my orders table. This is what the 2 tables look like
Customers table = custNum, custName, custAddress, custPhone
Orders table = orderNum, orderItem, custNum, price, qty

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - change the query that works.  Instead of selecting just the customer name, select the customer id, or whatever the primary key of that table is.

Step 2 - when displaying your data, add an anchor tag with a query string that links to a new page showing the orders.  The html should look like something like this:

```
<a href="orders.aspx?customer_id=1">Fred</a>
```

In orders.aspx, call a query that brings back all the orders for customer_id = 1.

Oh, yes, by the way, convert all form and url variables to parameters before sending them to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you only need to define a "Foreign Key" between the two tables, you can see this article to know how:

[www.codeproject.com/Articles/28273/Xml-Database-Demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28273/Xml-Database-Demo)

Read the "**Adding the DataTable Relation**" section.

If you had made your db with Access, you have to the same thing. The same thing if you're using SQL.